# regex ignore (stop capture) strings encapsulated in square brackets

Tags: php, regex

I have a string containing text, in this text there are several domains included such as google.de www.google.de etc...
I want to capture these, but ignore domain encapsulated in square brackets. At the moment I have the following:

https://regex101.com/r/t8IMd1/3

It doesn't ignore the encapsulated one though I used a negative lookahead.

What I have to do if more than one domain is in one line?

---

I don't get it at the moment, so I try to list all requirements and hope someone can provide a explained solution:

- domain names can be www.domain.de || domain.de || domain.de/something
- its a multiline text string, so the domains can occur on one line beside each other or in different lines
- they are divided by one or more whitespaces
- when domains are encapsulated in [domain] or [noscript]domain[/noscript] they have to be ignored

Comment: You may use [`\[[^]]*](*SKIP)(*F)|(?:www\.)?\w+\.[A-Za-z]{2,5}`](https://regex101.com/r/3BC4IC/2)

Comment: and be careful that's not a good regex for matching domain names.

Comment: Thx, what I have to do if more than one domain is in one line?